# Customize PDF bookmarks

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

I have the following document (this is an example):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\title{Sample document}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\frontmatter

\pagestyle{plain} 
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\part{My first part}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{First section}
A text...
\chapter{Other chapter}
Other text...

\part{My second part}
\chapter{Another chapter}
Yet another text...

\end{document}
```

And the PDF bookmarks that is being produced do not satisfy my needs. I needed:

- A root node "Sample document" pointing to the begining of first page of the document (title page)
- Contents page (TOC) appearing like one document part on bookmarks (but not in TOC, I don't want it to appear in TOC, only in Bookmarks)
- Instead of "I My first part" I wanted "Part I: My first part" and so on to the other parts
- Instead of "A chapter" I wanted "1 A chapter", instead of "Other chapter" I wanted "2 Another Chapter" and so on
- The section would continue to appear as it currently does on bookmarks, with no numbers, only its title

How can I do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use the [`bookmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) package. For example:

```
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
```

causes numbered bookmarks, such as the desired *2 Other chapter*.

```
\bookmark[page=1,level=0]{Sample document}
```

At the beginning gives you the desired first bookmark.
It offers many more features described in the documentation. Just follow the link above to CTAN or type `texdoc bookmark` at the command prompt.

Answer (score 19):

I solved my bookmarks problem using Stefan suggestion. I'm posting here what I did, so It may help anyone that comes to this question and is facing the same issues.

Adding the root node:

`\bookmark[page=1,level=-2]{Sample document}`

Adding the contents page to Bookmarks and not to table of contents:

```
\hypertarget{tocpage}{}
\tableofcontents
\bookmark[dest=tocpage,level=-1]{Contents}
```

Changing "I My first part" to "Part I: My first part":

```
\part*{My first part}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part I: My first part}
```

Changing "A chapter" to "1 A chapter" on bookmarks:

```
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
```

Comment: FYI, to add a bookmark linked to the slide with the outline in Beamer, I found it is more appropriate to use `\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=-1]{Contents}` as it enables to correctly handle outer theme elements.