# Evaluation order during macro expansion.

Tags: expansion

From this question [Creating PDF bookmarks in custom order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16908/creating-pdf-bookmarks-in-custom-order) arose another. (I hope it is correct to create a new question instead of commenting or editing/answering my old question.)

Using this macro (after creating counter `nops`):

```
\newcommand{\nop}{
  \stepcounter{nops}\hypertarget{nop\arabic{nops}}{}
  \BookmarkAtEnd{
    \bookmark[dest=nop\arabic{nops}]{page \arabic{nops}}
  }
}
```

I want `\nop` to mark the current place and add a bookmark to it to the end of my bookmark list. what happens is that the correct number of bookmarks is created, but they all reference the last occurence of `\nop`. It seems that this is because the text within `\BookmarkAtEnd` is practically copied to the end instead of inserting the current values first. How can i change this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\BookmarkAtEnd` simply stores the token list given as its argument, but you need that `\arabic{nops}` is expanded before storing.

The more common trick is to say

```
\newcommand{\nop}{%
  \stepcounter{nops}\hypertarget{nop\arabic{nops}}{}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\BookmarkAtEnd{%
    \noexpand\bookmark[dest=nop\arabic{nops}]{page \arabic{nops}}}}\x
}
```

The `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` are used just in order to avoid that `\x` has a definition after being used. We protect from expansion the commands `\BookmarkAtEnd` and `\bookmark` (`\endgroup` doesn't need to be protected because it's unexpandable); in this way the token list to be stored will contain the actual value of `nops` and not a command to get at its representation.

#### Update

With a recent TeX distribution you can exploit `expl3` and obtain an abstraction which you can then use also for other counters.

```latex
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\nop}{}
 {
  \peter_bookmark:nne { nop } { nops } { \arabic{nops} }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \peter_bookmark:nnn
 {
  \stepcounter{#2}
  \hypertarget{#1#3}{}
  \BookmarkAtEnd{\bookmark[dest=#1#3]{page~#3}}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \peter_bookmark:nnn { nne }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The idea is to expand the third argument of `\peter_bookmark:nnn` before expanding it, which is obtained by using the `e` variant.

Comment: There is a } missing before \x, but otherwise it works! Thank you.

Comment: @peter: Oops, corrected.