# What is the difference between passing optional and mandatory arguments?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I wanted to define a macro which makes a program listing, and finds out a program language
from an optional argument. The output I receive from the MWE below is

Language set = 'Verilog'

Passed argument is 'Verilog'

So, is looks like that in both calls to '\lstset' the same argument is passed.
However, if the argument is produced from optional, rather than a mandatory argument,
I am presented with the error message: "language Verilog undefined".
What do I wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{MESourceFile}{language}{\def\pb@language{#1}}
\setkeys{MESourceFile}{language={[ANSI]C}}%
\newcommand\MESourceFile[4][]{
   \begingroup%
    \setkeys{MESourceFile}{#1}
        Passed argument is '\pb@language'\\
    \lstset{language={\pb@language}}    
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\MESetListingFormat[2][] 
{
    Language set = '#2' 
    \lstset{language={#2}}  e   
}

\begin{document}
        \MESetListingFormat{Verilog}
        \MESourceFile[language=Verilog]{lst/TestHello.c}{A hello világ program}{lst:TestHello.c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.
A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Try, instead of `\lstset{language={\pb@language}}`, the code `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\lstset{language=\pb@language}}\x`

Comment: @ Martin Schröder Sorry for being unpolite, but: I could not find out how to register, or change user name. From your homepage I learned "No registration required". In the Help center, I took the "2-minute tour", which takes back to the Help center. Even Google takes to the "No registration required" page. When asking, I do not see an obvious possibility to register or provide username. Some hint on the homepage would be great. @egreg Many thanks, it works. Is there a more elegant method, than checking for empty string, for absence of an argument? A link to your info source would be great.

Comment: @user11708 It's true that “no registration is required”, but a registered user can better enjoy the site. The `\begingroup\edef\x` trick is very common; you need nothing special if the argument is empty, as `\setkeys` happily accepts an empty argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an expansion problem: when the key is set, no expansion is performed, so you have to pass the expanded `\pb@language` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{MESourceFile}{language}{\def\pb@language{#1}}
\setkeys{MESourceFile}{language={[ANSI]C}}
\newcommand\MESourceFile[4][]{%
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{MESourceFile}{#1}
%    Passed argument is '\pb@language'\\% uncomment for debugging
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\lstset{language={\pb@language}}}\x
  \lstinputlisting{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\MESourceFile[language=Verilog]{helloworld.v}{A hello világ program}{helloworld.v}

\end{document}
```

However, it would be easier to do it using `\lstset` directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MESourceFile}[4][]{%
  \begingroup
  \lstset{#1}%
  \lstinputlisting{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\MESourceFile[language=Verilog]{helloworld.v}{A hello világ program}{helloworld.v}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Source of the listing: http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/first1.html

See [Explanations about \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61223/explanations-about-begingroup-edef-x-endgroup) for an explanation of the trick.

Comment: I do use \lstset in \MESetListingFormat directly. I do work on multi-language document, and I want to do a uniform look for the listings (the MWE is oversimplified). This default argument looks to be a better idea than adding an extra mandatory parameter.