# downgrade pgfmath

Tags: pgfmath

This is the first time I do not receive any answers to my problem with pgfmath, and I would like to proceed, so I ask whether and how I can downgrade it?

[tikz/pgf upgrade and decorations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239985/tikz-pgf-upgrade-and-decorations)

As I mentioned, with the 2010 version my solution worked

Comment: Assuming you have a backup of the old installation, you could remove the current version of `tikz` and `pgf` and copy in the old version.  However, many updates for other packages may not work as expected because they might depend on new features introduced with the latest version of `pgf`.

Comment: Or, you could just move the current version of `pgfmath.tex` to `pgfmath.new.txt` and copy the old version in its place.  Yet, again, this may have some unexpected results since the rest of `pgf` and `tikz` are written expecting the most recent version of `pgfmath.tex`.

Comment: Well, in my OSX I did have a disk failure, in my Linux I have a brand-new installation, so I really do not have old installation.  Otherwise,  thanks to this pgfmath upgrade, about 80% of my work compiles ONLY with the new version, and 20% ONLY with the old version. It looks like the only way out is to re-develop my own macros, to circumvent this bug in the new version. Hopefully, while I am working, the developers can fix the bug, and then I can continue developing in the backward direction. I guessed that the new version was tested. I provided MWE.

Comment: It looks like you can get version 2.10 of pgf at [here](http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/pkg/pgf.html) except the link is broken.... :(

Comment: Is there no `compat` option?

Comment: There is no reason for downgrading. Your code was faulty; I fixed it.