# listings: How to Annotate a Matlab Listing (Matlab Code) (curly brackets, arrows, text)

Tags: listings, matlab, matlab2tikz

I have a matlab code and I want explain part of them like picture.
or any other idea can do better.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}


\begin{document}


\lstset{language=Matlab,%
    %basicstyle=\color{red},
    breaklines=true,%
    morekeywords={matlab2tikz},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
    morekeywords=[2]{1}, keywordstyle=[2]{\color{black}},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},%
    stringstyle=\color{mylilas},
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},%
    showstringspaces=false,%without this there will be a symbol in the places where there is a space
    numbers=left,%
    numberstyle={\tiny \color{black}},% size of the numbers
    numbersep=9pt, % this defines how far the numbers are from the text
    emph=[1]{for,end,break},emphstyle=[1]\color{red}, %some words to emphasise
    %emph=[2]{word1,word2}, emphstyle=[2]{style},    
}


\section*{Matlab Code}

‎\lstinputlisting{WEIGHT.m}‎


\end{document}
```

`WEIGHT.m` matlab file

```
clc
clear all
n=input('Please Enter Number Of Grid Point    n=');
      %-------------
      x=zeros(n,1);A=zeros(n,n);
      %-------------
      for i=1:n
        x(i)=0.5*(1-cos((i-1)*pi/(n-1))); 
      end
      for i=1:n
         for j=1:n
              Pi=1;Pj=1;
            for m=1:n 
               if m~=i  
                  Pi=(x(i)-x(m))*Pi;
               end
               if m~=j  
                  Pj=(x(j)-x(m))*Pj;
               end   
            end
            if i~=j 
               A(i,j)=Pi/((x(i)-x(j))*Pj);
            end   
         end  
         for m=1:n  
             if m~=i
                A(i,i)=A(i,i)-A(i,m);
             end
         end   
      end
```

Comment: I guess the tikz package is your friend. I'm no expert, but the following tex.sx question may give you some hints: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97887/tikz-curly-braces-end-at-the-same-node-but-there-is-a-gap

Comment: ...and these http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266473/28808 http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240734/28808. Searching this site for "[tikz] [listings]" will give you lots of hints.

Comment: Why not simply write comments in the code itself? Also, you may be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Comment: thank you, it was better if I can write like picture. I think readers like to read code like above picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution with `tikz`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.pathreplacing, positioning}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        node distance=.2cm,
        code/.style={rectangle,draw=cyan!50,fill=cyan!20,thick,
                      inner sep=1cm,minimum size=2mm},
        place/.style={rectangle,draw=green!50,fill=green!20,thick,
                      inner sep=0cm,minimum size=6mm}           
    ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

     \node[code]  (A) [text width=13cm]
     { 
        ‎\lstinputlisting[%##########################
                         style=Matlab-editor,
                         basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
                         escapechar         = ",
                         ]%#########################    
        {WEIGHT.m} 
     ‎};

     \node  (1) [left=of  A,yshift= 5.2cm] {};
     \node  (2) [below=of 1,yshift=-7mm] {};
     \draw[very thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]  (1.east) -- (2.east) 
           node[midway,left]{\Large{\textbf{1} $\leftarrow$}};

     \node  (3) [below=of 2,yshift= 3mm] {};
     \node  (4) [below=of 3,yshift=-6mm] {};
     \draw[very thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]  (3.east) -- (4.east)
          node[midway,left]{\Large{\textbf{2 important} $\leftarrow$}};

     \node  (5) [below=of 4,yshift=  3mm] {};
     \node  (6) [below=of 5,yshift=-83mm] {};
     \draw[very thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]  (5.east) -- (6.east)
          node[midway,left]{\Large{\textbf{3 Loop} $\leftarrow$}};

     \node  (7) [below=of 6,yshift= 4mm] {};
     \node  (8) [below=of 7,yshift=-1mm] {};
     \draw[very thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]  (7.east) -- (8.east)
          node[midway,left]{\Large{\textbf{4 final} $\leftarrow$}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]