# ConTeXt: Macro within macro for URLs

Tags: macros, context, expansion, urls, context-mkiv

## Background

Would like to define a base URL that can be reused by other macros.

## Problem

Using the `\goto` macro requires a fully expanded URL.

## Minimum Working Example

Here's code that illustrates the problem:

```
\setupinteraction[state=start]

\def\WPhomepagebase{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/}
\def\WPpagequestion{\WPhomepagebase{}201545}
%\def\WPpagequestion{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201545}

\def\href#1#2{%
  \goto{#1}[url(#2)]%
}

\starttext
  \href{TeX StackExchange}{\WPpagequestion}
\stoptext
```

If the code is changed as follows:

```
%\def\WPhomepagebase{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/}
%\def\WPpagequestion{\WPhomepagebase{}201545}
\def\WPpagequestion{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201545}
```

Then the document produces the correct hyperlink.

## Question

How do you use `\goto` within a custom macro, as shown in the example code, such that the URL can contain other macros?

Comment: Untested: you can use `\edef\WPpagequestion{...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In every case below, remove the extraneous braces:

```
\def\WPpagequestion{\WPhomepagebase 201545}
```

to prevent those braces from being included in the URL.

### Plain TeX

A Plain TeX way for solving this would be:

```
\def\href#1#2{%
  \begingroup\def\x{\endgroup\goto{#1}[url(}%
  \expandafter\x#2)]%
}
```

or the more drastic:

```
\def\href#1#2{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\goto{#1}[url(#2)]}\x
}
```

where `\noexpand` is possibly redundant, if `\goto` is a protected macro.

### ConTeXt expanded Macro

As per the comments, in ConTeXt, the `\expanded` macro can be used:

```
\define[2]\href{%
  \expanded{%
    \goto{#1}[url(#2)]%
  }%
}
```

### ConTeXt edef Macro

This can be simplified further using `\edef`:

```
\def\WPhomepagebase{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/}
\edef\WPpagequestion{\WPhomepagebase 201545}

\define[2]\href{%
  \goto{#1}[url(#2)]%
}
```

### See Also

- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/begingroup
- [When should one use \begingroup instead of \bgroup?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1930/2148)
- [Explanations about \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61223/2148)

Comment: ConTeXt has a `\expanded` command which can be used here, i.e. the `\href`command could be defined as `\define[2]\href{\expanded{\goto{#1}[url(#2)]}}`.

Comment: @Metafox The definition is like `\def\expanded#1{\xdef\tmp{\noexpand#1}\tmp}`. What is the purpose of `\noexpand` there?

Comment: @Manuel, without the noexpand, the goto in the above example will be expanded.