# part bookmarks and toc style

Tags: bookmarks, parts

Within the `book.cls` class, I redefined the `\part` section to customize the respective toc entry as follows:

```
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\noindent\fcolorbox{ocre}{black!5}{\protect\makebox[\linewidth-2\fboxsep]{\Large\sffamily\strut #1}}}%
\else%
...
```

The problem is that the `\fcolorbox` somehow does not go well with the created part bookmark in the pdf file. For instance, instead of `parttitle`, I am getting the following bookmark in the built pdf file:

```
push0 g 0 Gpop[-2]parttitleocreblack!5push0 g 0 Gpoptowidthheightdepthottheight-0.5 -widthheightdepthd- widthheightdepthheightted
```

I have been trying some `\protect` commands, without success so far. Would you be aware of a systematic way to correct this behavior. If not, I can still redefine the part titles directly in the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter

\def\@myparttocformat #1{\noindent
    \fcolorbox{cyan}{black!5}
       {\makebox[\linewidth-2\fboxsep-\@pnumwidth]{\Large\sffamily\strut #1}}}

\def\@part[#1]#2{%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax 
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline {toc}{part}
     {\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
  \else
 \addcontentsline {toc}{part}{#1}\fi \markboth {}{}{\centering \interlinepenalty \@M \normalfont \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax \huge \bfseries \partname \nobreakspace \thepart \par \vskip 20\p@ \fi \Huge \bfseries #2\par }\@endpart }

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Hello}

\chapter{A chapter}

world

\end{document}
```

I did this to keep close to your skeleton of a mwe, however, I would much rather redefine `\l@part`. (do not know in which device name xcolor option `ocre` is defined)

The hyperref link would admittedly then be only on the actual name of the Part, and not like here the entire shaded and framed box. But the whole thing would be cleaner.

[image: toc]

with the bookmarks shown (now in Acrobat):

[image: toc with acroread]

Comment: Nice. Do you know why the part and chapter numbers are not included in the bookmarks?

Comment: I think they never are for chapters and sections. They are for parts because standard LaTeX puts different things in the toc file then (no `\numberline` but a `\hspace{1em}`) and (I did not investigate more), presumably hyperref just filters out the `\hspace{1em}` which leaves the part number. Yes, I just tried with the memoir class and then even the parts do not get numbers in the bookmarks (`memoir` uses `\partnumberline`, `\chapternumberline`, ...)

Comment: I just found a possible answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11867/customize-pdf-bookmarks/11875#11875

Comment: yes, that gives a fix. But does one really want numbers in bookmarks? bookmarks are supposed to be clicked upon... and the TOC already has the numbers.

Comment: correct but when the document is long, numbered bookmarks do help a bit. Also, it looks like the `\texorpdfstring` command removes the automatic bookmark numbering.