# How to add additional entries to PDF(-Viewer) TOC but not regular TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm creating a book'ish document using `\phantomsection\addcontentsline...` to add custom table-of-contents (TOC) entries. I'd like a few special entries to show up only in the PDF reader's TOC panel, but not in my regular book's TOC. For example the TOC itself, the cover page and the backcover page.

How can I set/mark TOC entries to only affect the PDF TOC? Using xelatex if that makes a difference.

Comment: You can use the \pdfbookmark command or  the commands of the bookmark package.

Comment: Maybe also relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11867/277964

Comment: \pdfbookmark works like a charm once I figured out the [level] is relative to current (not mentioned in docs). I prefer that solution over the bookmark package mentioned in the other SE question as I already have hyperref loaded.